# Android Using baseadapter to update a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

So i've been developing my first app, and it's been a great learning experience. I wanted next to take my app and create a widget-form of it to put on the home screen. Currently my app shows the currently open apps running on the system, and I wanted to create a widget that shows the top 4. But since the way android dev pages have you do a widget is by using `RemoteViews` and an `AppWidgetManager`, it's not possible to use `findViewById()` and update the XML of your widget page directly.

```
public class blah extends Activity
    {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        openApps(Gridview, PackageManager);
    }

    public openApps(final GridView g, final PackageManager pm){
        //Make a custom List<AppInfo>
        //Algorithm to get currently open apps
        //list.add(new appinfo(process name, icon))
        //g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this/*Context*/, List<AppInfo>, PackageManager)
    }
}
```

The way i have it implemented in the app is basically
 to do an algorithm to get the open apps into a list, then use `GridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context, list))` that updates the activity UI. Is there a way to do this with a widget (class that extends `AppWidgetProvider`)?

I'm not looking for the code, just an idea to try to get me started. 
Thanks for any possible help!